# Stripping capital letters from everything in a column in the database

Tags: php, mysql, database, phpmyadmin

I know lots of people have answered this question but I am following the guides but I am getting nowhere

I am currently using

```
UPDATE buinesses 
SET BusinessType = LOWER(BusinessType)
```

I have want to stop all of the caps from the business names for example:

I would like 'Cafe and Post Office' to be 'cafe and post office'

I would do this manually but I have over 500 business types in my database.

Comment: Do you want to remove them or make them lowercase ?

Comment: I want to make them lowercase :)

Comment: Then your query should be correct. Check if the table name and fields are ok.

Comment: According to this http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-lower-function.php , your query should work .

Answer (score 0):

Use PHP's `strtolower()`

```
$string = "A Very Stupid String with Some CapitaL Letters";
echo strtolower($string);
```

Note that your current query `UPDATE buinesses SET BusinessType=LOWER(BusinessType)` will also convert the Businesstype to a lowercase string.

Answer (score -1):

Really sorry but it worked

```
UPDATE buinesses SET BusinessType=LOWER(BusinessType)
```

for some reason it didnt update when i first did it

Comment: You may have forgotten to commit :)